# Can't log into Storm UI with Kerberos

Tags: apache-storm

I have the Storm UI (version 1.0.2) up and running with Kerberos, and it appears to work. The logs indicate that it successfully authenticated and there are no exceptions. Now I want to connect to the UI from the local machine. I have read all the docs I could find, for example https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/1.0.x-branch/SECURITY.md

As I understand it, I need to set properties like so, with the important part being the rules at the end. What I believe it's doing is establishing a mapping that says "no matter what principal the client authenticates as in MYREALM, map it to myUser in the UI itself"

```
ui.filter: "org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter"
ui.filter.params:
  "type": "kerberos"
  "kerberos.principal": "KRB principal that the UI connects as"
  "kerberos.keytab": "path to that user's keytab"
  "kerberos.name.rules": "RULE:[2:$1@$0](.*@MYREALM)s/.*/myUser/"
```

Then on my client, I run the following

```
kinit -kt <keytab> <same kerberos principal that the UI connects as>
curl -i --negotiate -u:myUser -b ~/cookiejar.txt -c ~/cookiejar.txt http://<ui hostname>:8080/api/v1/cluster/summary
```

No matter what I put into the -u, I get a 401. Here's what I don't understand:

1. If I ran kinit, I have now authenticated as a certain Kerberos principal. Then I run curl. **Why do I have to give curl a user id and what should it be?** In the filter above, I already told it that whatever principal I send should be mapped to myUser, so shouldn't it just work?
2. Perhaps the problem is the myUser. I don't know how in the Storm UI configuration to tell it that myUser is the local user I want

Once curl works, then I just have to do the same thing from a browser.

I feel as if I'm missing something about how all these pieces fit together. I'm also fairly new to Kerberos, so it's quite possible I'm messing that up as well.

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to solve this? I'm having the same error?

Comment: I believe the issue was the kerberos.name.rules. The docs give a cryptic value for that property and I tried to modify it for my situation. For example, it refers to $MAPRED_USER but I'm running outside of Hadoop. In the end, it didn't work until I just used exactly what the docs said, even though it didn't fully make sense. e.g. "RULE:[2:$$1@$$0]([jt]t@.*<realm>)s/.*/$MAPRED_USER/ RULE:[2:$$1@$$0]([nd]n@.*<realm>)s/.*/$HDFS_USER/DEFAULT"